# How to show callout view(custom view) on user current location button(blue dot)

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I have used react-native-map please help me how to show custom view on user location click without using any other custom marker.
Thanks in Advance.

import  {MapView, Circle, Marker,Callout } from 'react-native-maps';

{this.state.showView != true &&

```
    <MapView
    provider={"google"}
    region={mapRegion}
    style={styles.map}
    showsUserLocation = {true}

    clusterColor = 'black'
    clusterTextColor = 'white'
    clusterBorderColor = 'black'
    clusterBorderWidth = {1}
    pinColor = 'red'
    showsMyLocationButton = {false}

    >
```